# RegEx Escaping Comma

Tags: c#, regex

How do I escape the following regular expression?

```
Match match = Regex.Match(response.Content, @"([0-9]+)","display");
```

I've tried escaping the double quotes, but the comma is causing VS to think that "display" is a third argument to the Match method.

Comment: I don't get it.  Why isn't the comma just part of the quoted string that is the RegEx?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Match match = Regex.Match(response.Content, @"([0-9]+)"",""display");
```

?

Answer (score 0):

VS is right. Match method is overloaded but doesn't accept 3 strings as parameters. 
Match(String)
Match(String, Int32)
Match(String, String)
Match(String, Int32, Int32)
Match(String, String, RegexOptions)
Match(String, String, RegexOptions, TimeSpan)
Hope this helps.